chktex Warning in VSCode
No matter what document I compile in VSCode, I get the warning

chktex: WARNING -- Compilation of regular expression [(?![^][{}]{(?![^][{}]}))[^]]*[ failed with error repetition-operator operand invalid. Source: LaTeX

Even when compiling
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}
hello
\end{document}

The pdf has no problem compiling, but I get the annoying message.
How do I get rid of this?

the error is not from latex it's from chktex. You should probably show your vscode configuration to show how you are calling chktex, do you get the same error when directly calling chktex with the same options, directly via the commandline not using vscode?

This is a duplicate of another question but I guess I don't have the karma to mark it as such.
To make a long story short, it's a bug in the chktexrc that was distributed, but should be fixed with the latest version uploaded to CTAN.  Unfortunately, I'm not sure how long it will take the vscode extension to update their version (or your TeX distribution if they rely on that).
If you can find the chktexrc file that's being used (it seems like some people on the other question didn't find the right one since it's probably bundled with the vscode extension), then you should be able to remove the offending line (around line 247).

I would say your answer is better than the one of the duplicate question because it clarifies what exactly to do. Only with your answer I was able to get rid of this issue.
